# Stack two numpy array of two different shape

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, dictionary

I have two NumPy arrays.

One has the dimension (4,1).

[image]

Another numpy array I have with teh dimension of (240, 320)
[image]

Now, I want to make a CSV file that will look like this:
[image]

As the two numpy array size is different, how can i stack them ? any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot stack two arrays without the same shape according to [numpy.stack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html). However, you can save the arrays sequentially to a csv file to obtain the result you seek. The following code must do the tricks.

```py
import numpy as np

mat0 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4, 1), dtype=int)
mat1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (240, 320), dtype=int)

with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, mat0, delimiter=',')
    np.savetxt(f, mat1, delimiter=',')
```